# Ignore spaces in string comparison with array

Tags: perl

my array will have the following values

```
array values will be like 

    "hi hello",
    "what are",
    "do you",
    "see here"
```

How to find the array has the value `"hihello"`.

i used like the following to check this.

```
if ( trim($value) ~~ @array)
```

since array has space while value don't have, it doesn't give true. Is there any easy way without loop ?

Answer (score 5):

Which `trim` are you referring to? Smart match [~~ operator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#The_smartmatch_family_of_features_are_now_experimental) is experimental as of `5.18`.

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my @array = (
  "hi hello",
  "what are",
  "do you",
  "see here"
);

# similar to grep(), first() also aliases $_ to array elements so changes
# to $_ directly affect array elements
# print "found it\n" if first { tr| ||d; $_ eq "hihello" } @array;
#
# non destructive translation, but it requires perl 5.12
# print "found it\n" if first { tr| ||dr eq "hihello" } @array;

print "found it\n" if first {
  (my $s = $_) =~ tr| ||d;
  $s eq "hihello";
} @array;
```

Comment: Interesting, did not know about "first" in List::Util

Comment: @Paul it is similar to grep but should be faster as it doesn't go trough all list elements.

Comment: `any` from List::MoreUtils (and also in recent releases of List::Util) might be better than `first`. For example, if you were searching for the string `"0"` instead of `"hihello"`.

Comment: @tobyink https://eval.in/84377 `List::MoreUtils` is great but unfortunately not part of standard perl like `List::Util`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.12;

my @array = ( "hi hello", "what are", "do you", "see here" );
my $value = "hihello";

print qq/"$value" /,
  ( grep s/\s+//gr eq $value, @array ) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Output:

```
"hihello" found
```

The `/r` modifier (Per v5.12+) in the substitution returns the modified string.  However, this solution doesn't terminate iterating through the entire list upon a find, as [mpapec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/mpapec)'s solution using `List::Util qw(first)` does.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `trim` removes only the spaces that are before or after the text, not the spaces in the middle.

If you don't like `for` loops, Perl has `grep` and `map` as well as `foreach`.  Internally I believe these are all loops.

It might be useful to read through some of the perl turorials and documentation on your PC. If it is not on your PC, try http://perldoc.perl.org/